# Python Beautifulsoup get titles from date range

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get titles, links and dates from a date range, like Fourdaysago to today.
First I choose Current Month in the dropdown select option, and then choose dates which between the range.
I use:

```
html_link = 'https://www.ksei.co.id/publications/new-securities-registration?setLocale=en-US'
html = requests.get(html_link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
now = datetime.datetime.now()
month = now.month
soup.select('(option["{}"])'.format(month))
FourDaysAgo = (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days = 4))
FourDaysAgo_day = FourDaysAgo.day
now = datetime.date.today()
today = now.day
d = range(FourDaysAgo_day,today)
```

And I would like to get the titles and hrefs in that date range, but I cannot figure out how to put the date as a 'select condition'
I use:

```
dates = soup.findAll('b', text = re.compile('{}').format(d))
titles = soup.find_all("h2", {"class": "h4 no-margin"})
hrefs = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "btn btn--primary"})
```

Could someone please help?

Comment: Do you want to always get the current month?

Comment: Hi, yes, as I wanna check the latest update

Comment: Which item is the title?

Comment: like```KSEI-3512/DIR/0521 ```text in the xpath```/html/body/main/div/div[1]/div[2]/article/ul/li[1]/article/div/div[1]/h2```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code can be refined, but it should solve your use case.  If you have any issues please let me know and I will try to address them.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from dateutil.parser import parse
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


four_days_ago = (parse((datetime.now() - timedelta(days=10)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))
start_date = datetime.strptime(str(four_days_ago), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
end_date = datetime.strptime(str(datetime.now()), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


html_link = 'https://www.ksei.co.id/publications/new-securities-registration?setLocale=en-US'
html = requests.get(html_link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for ultag in soup.find_all('ul', {'class': 'list-nostyle'}):
    for litag in ultag.find_all('li'):
        for dates in litag.find_all('small', {'class': 'muted'}):
            clean_date = datetime.strptime(str(dates.text), "%B %d, %Y").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            if start_date <= clean_date <= end_date:
                title = litag.find('h2', {'class': 'h4 no-margin'})
                document_link = litag.find('a', href=True)
                print(clean_date)
                print(title.text)
                print(f"https://www.ksei.co.id{document_link['href']}")
                # OUTPUT
                2021-05-11
                KSEI-3629/DIR/0521 
                https://www.ksei.co.id/Announcement/Files/127505_ksei_3629_dir_0521_202105140513.pdf
                2021-05-06
                KSEI-3512/DIR/0521 
                https://www.ksei.co.id/Announcement/Files/127181_ksei_3512_dir_0521_202105070825.pdf
                2021-05-05
                KSEI-3482/DIR/0521 
                https://www.ksei.co.id/Announcement/Files/127076_ksei_3482_dir_0521_202105051506.pdf
                truncated...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! but should I pick the current month first? or the website is set to pick the latest month automatically?

Comment: if I change start date to ```start_date = datetime.strptime(str(datetime.now()), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")```, and to use for the last ten days, nothing returns

Comment: The date code needed to be changed.  The code will now get the items for the last 10 days.

Comment: The website seems to be defaulting to the current month, so you shouldn't have to select the month on query.

Comment: Did you ever try this code? If so, did it work for you?  If not why?  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply! I have tried your code, it returns an error:```TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'```

Comment: That error was caused by this line - if start_date <= parse(clean_date) <= end_date: - I forgot to remove the - parse() when I updated my answer.  It should work now.

Comment: Hey, it works form my side! thank you so much for your help and the following!

Comment: I'm happy that it worked.  I should have cut and pasted all my code instead of the snippets that lead to the error.   BTW You're posting some interesting questions, which makes solving them more intriguing.

Comment: It works just fine : ) Thanks! I am quiet new for coding, so sometimes may need help lol, and thanks for helping me several times : )

Comment: @Joyce we were all new coders at one time in our lives.  Just keep learning and writing, because you will get better.  Happy Coding!!

Comment: sure thing! just find coding interesting and will keep learning : ) Happy Coding!